# Database size after deleting rows does not change

Tags: sql-server, database

I have 2 databases from which I have deleted rows in a specific table in order to decrease the size of the database.

After deleting, the size of `DB.mdf` does not change.

I also tried to rebuild the index and used `cleantable`, but to no effect!

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON dbo.'Tablename' REBUILD

DBCC CLEANTABLE ('DBname', 'Tablename', 0)
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to shrink the db.  Right click db, Tasks->Shrink database

Answer (score 6):

Deleting rows in a database will not decrease the actual database file size.

You need to compact the database after row deletion.

[Look for this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190488(v=sql.90).aspx) 
After running this, you'll want to rebuild indexes. Shrinking typically causes index fragmentation, and that could be a significant performance cost.

I would also recommend that after you shrink, you re-grow the files so that you have some free space. That way, when new rows come in, they don't trigger autogrowth. Autogrowth has a performance cost and is something you would like to avoid whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced the same issue, my db was 40MB after deleting some columns still its size was not getting changed..
I installed SQLManager then opened my db and used command 'vaccum' that cleaned my db and its size got reduced to 10MB.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this after being in the exact same scenario and needing to shrink the database. However, not wanting to use DBCC SHRINFKILE I used Paul Randals method of shrinking the database.

https://gist.github.com/tcartwright/ea60e0a38fac25c847e39bced10ecd04