# Does deleting the rows from table also release space of large objects in CLOB or BLOB columns?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

Size of large objects is not shown with table size where queried through dba_segments where table_name=abc so does deleting the rows from table also release space of large objects in CLOB or BLOB columns in those tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete the rows having large LOB objects then oracle does not free the space to the tablespace automatically.

You will need to claim the space(size) which will be released to your tablespace using following query:

```
ALTER TABLE <YourTable> MODIFY LOB (<LobColumn>) (SHRINK SPACE);
```

You can calculate the total size of the LOB segment using the following query:

```
SELECT OWNER,SEGMENT_NAME,ROUND(SUM(BYTES)/1024/1024) "LOB size (mb)" 
FROM DBA_SEGMENTS
WHERE SEGMENT_NAME IN 
    (
    SELECT SEGMENT_NAME 
    FROM DBA_LOBS WHERE TABLE_NAME = <YOURTABLE>
    AND OWNER = <YOUROWNER>
    )
GROUP BY OWNER,SEGMENT_NAME;
```

You can calculate the size before and after deletion of record and you will find no difference, but once you execute the aforementioned `ALTER TABLE` command (after deleting the rows), you will see difference in size using the above query.

Cheers!!

Comment: Your ALTER TABLE command seems to require ASSM in order to work. ORA-10635: Invalid segment or tablespace type
10635. 00000 -  "Invalid segment or tablespace type"
*Cause:    Cannot shrink the segment because it is not in auto segment space
           managed tablespace or it is not a data, index or lob segment.

Comment: Your query will only show space for the table segment, not the LOB segment. The LOB segment name starts with 'SYS_LOB%'.

Comment: @Stew Ashton --> Yes, according to oracle documentation: **Shrink operations can be performed only on segments in locally managed tablespaces with automatic segment space management (ASSM)** . Query to calculate the LOB segment size is updated

Comment: So is it possible to shrink space through the mentioned ALTER TABLE statement ONLINE?
I am using version 11g

Answer (score 0):

If the table is not big, you have sufficient space in the tablespace and you do not have permission of `ALTER TABLE`, then I would suggest the approach below.

After deletion of records

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_LOB_TABLE AS SELECT * FROM ORIGINAL_LOB_TABLE
DROP ORIGINAL_LOB_TABLE
RENAME NEW TABLE TO ORIGINAL TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer, my db was 40 DB it got reduced to 10 db after using 'Vaccum' command in SQLManager
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62749800/4571399

Comment: That is for SQL Server ; this question was for oracle